# Excel tables columns with different colour

Tags: excel

I have a huge table and want to have a different colour scheme for different columns. For e.g. Can I have a table with 8 columns, 4 columns in red pattern, and 4 in green?

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in colour schemes or table styles for that. You can use banded columns, i.e. alternating colours for each column.  Anything other than "all columns the same" or "banded columns" will need to be formatted manually, via conditional formatting, or using VBA.

When you set up a format for a table column, new rows will inherit formatting, so you only need to apply the formatting to the table column once and all new or inserted rows will follow that defined format.

Comment: Thanks a lot, conditional formatting actually might work best, cheers

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using conditional formatting:

The following formula applies to: `=$1:$1` (Substituting 1 for Row, for Table Headings) and choosing a heading formatting as appropriate:

```
=AND(COLUMN()>{From Column Number},COLUMN()<{To Column Number})
```

Then apply the following conditional formatting to the entire table, again choose appropriate formatting for even rows in the table:

```
=AND(COLUMN()>{From Column Number},COLUMN()<{To Column Number},ISEVEN(ROW()))
```